# Distance traveled along each axis over a circular arc

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find a simpler/faster numerical formula or algorithm to calculate the total distance traveled along each axis, $L_x$ and $L_y$, over a circular arc.

Essentially, I am separating the "movement" along the circular arc to movements along the $x$ and $y$ axes, and measuring the total travel along each axis.

The arc is defined by the endpoints and the radius, and optionally the center of the arc.

Because the calculations are done numerically on a low-power microcontroller, I wish to avoid trigonometric functions like $\arctan$.

Let's define the circular arc as a parametric curve $\vec{p}(t) = \left( x(t) ,\, y(t) \right)$, where $0 \le t \le 1$. Then,
$$L_x = \begin{cases}
\lvert x(1) - x(0) \rvert, & N_x = 0 \\
\lvert x(\tau_1) - x(0) \rvert + \lvert x(1) - x(\tau_1) \rvert, & N_x = 1 \\
\lvert x(\tau_1) - x(0) \rvert + \lvert x(1) - x(\tau_1) \rvert + \sum_{i=2}^{N_x} \lvert x(\tau_i) - x(\tau_{i-1}) \rvert, & N_x \ge 2 \end{cases}$$
where
$$0 \lt \tau_1 \lt \tau_2 \lt \dots \lt \tau_{N_x} \lt 1$$
and
$$\left. \frac{d \, x(t)}{ d\, t } \right\rvert_{t = \tau_i} = 0, \qquad i = 1 .. N_x$$

Similarly, for $y(t)$,
$$L_y = \begin{cases}
\lvert y(1) - y(0) \rvert, & N_y = 0 \\
\lvert y(\tau_1) - y(0) \rvert + \lvert y(1) - y(\tau_1) \rvert, & N_y = 1 \\
\lvert y(\tau_1) - y(0) \rvert + \lvert y(1) - y(\tau_1) \rvert + \sum_{i=2}^{N_y} \lvert y(t_i) - y(t_{i-1}) \rvert, & N_y \ge 2 \end{cases}$$
where
$$0 \lt t_1 \lt t_2 \lt \dots \lt t_{N_y} \lt 1$$
and
$$\left. \frac{d \, y(t)}{ d\, t } \right\rvert_{t = t_i} = 0, \qquad i = 1 .. N_y$$

As an example, consider a circular arc of radius $\sqrt{2}$, centered at origin $(0, 0)$.

If we draw an arc from $(1, 1)$ to $(-1, 1)$, the coordinate differences along each axis are $(\lvert 1 - (-1) \rvert ,\, \lvert 1 - 1 \rvert) = (2, 0)$, and $L_x = 2$, but $L_y = \lvert \sqrt{2} - 1 \rvert + \lvert 1 - \sqrt{2} \rvert = 2 \sqrt{2} - 2 \approx 0.828427$.

If we draw the arc from $(1, 0)$ to $(0, 1)$, then $L_x = 1$ and $L_y = 1$.

Here is a figure describing a circular arc from $(\sqrt{2}/2 ,\, \sqrt{2}/2)$ to $(-\sqrt{2}/2 ,\, \sqrt{2}/2)$:
[image: Circular arc with axis-aligned chord]

Comment: i don't understand what a crossed distance is

Comment: Oops, I assumed "the crossed distance" had "crossed" as in "walked", i.e. that the distance refers to the arc length. The numbers do not seem to indicate so, however.

Comment: okay what i mean by crossed distance is  "walked" as Nominal said ^^ , like when you move 1 meter forward and then one meter backward, you displacement is zero, but you actually walked 2 meters.

Comment: But.. Walking from $(-\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2)$ to $(\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2)$ along the unit circle, you walk $\pi/2 \approx 1.5708$, not $2 - \sqrt{2} \approx 0.5858$. The distance between the two endpoints is $2\sqrt{2}/2 = \sqrt{2} \approx 1.4142$. The $Y$ marked in the image is $1 - \sqrt{2}/2 \approx 0.2929$, and $2 Y = 2 - \sqrt{2}$. So, are you asking a generic formula for $2 Y$? Or are you asking the length of the circular arc, that in the example is $\pi/2$ and not $2 Y$?

Comment: Yes formula for 2Y, I don't need the arc length I need the horizontal and vertical components if I moved along the arc.

Comment: you just want the chord length?

Comment: @SakethMalyala: No, it's much more complicated. Consider the curve $( x(t), y(t) )$, for $0 \le t \le 1$. Split $x(t)$ into monotonic pieces, and convert each piece to the distance from its minimum to maximum, and sum them, to get the result along $x$ axis. Similarly for the $y$ axis. I wish I knew better terminology to describe this. (In this case, the curve is a circular arc with a known radius.)

Comment: so like you're breaking it down into a series of line segments and finding the combined length?

Comment: @SakethMalyala: No, each coordinate axis is treated completely separately. If we consider $x(t)$ for $0 \le t \le 1$, and there is one minimum or maximum within that interval at $\tau$, then the "length" for $x$ is $(x(\tau) - x(0)) + (x(\tau) - x(1))$.

Comment: Actually, I think I can express it in general form. Let $( x(t) ,\, y(t) )$ be the parametric form for the curve, here a circular arc, with $0 \le t \le 1$. Then, $$L_x = \begin{cases}\lvert x(1) - x(0) \rvert, & N = 0 \\ \lvert x(\tau_1) - x(0) \rvert + \lvert x(1) - x(\tau_1) \rvert, & N = 1 \\ \lvert x(\tau_1) - x(0) \rvert + \lvert x(1) - x(\tau_1) \rvert  + \sum_{i=2}^N \lvert x(\tau_i) - x(\tau_{i-1}) \rvert, & N \ge 2\end{cases}$$where $$0 \lt \tau_1 \lt \dots \lt \tau_N \lt 1$$ fulfill $$\left.\frac{d x(t)}{d t}\right\rvert_{t=\tau_i} = 0, \qquad i = 1 .. N$$and similarly for $L_y$.

Comment: @O.Emad: I hope you don't mind, and will consider my edit, in case it will pique the interest of some of the mathematicians here. I think my re-wording helps understand the problem from a mathematical viewpoint. The reason for me suggesting this rewrite is that there may still be an even simpler solution (perhaps via algebraic integration of the absolute value of the derivatives?), and I'd like the esteemed members here to consider this question. Feel free to reject the edit, if you think it does not reflect your question; I'm only trying to help, and it is **your** question.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: how you rephrased it actually reflects my question better, i'm totally fine with it.

Comment: @O.Emad: Good to hear. I do believe (but have not verified) that the simplest way to define $L_x$ and $L_y$ is $$L_x = \int \left\lvert \frac{d \, x(t)}{d \, t} \right\rvert_{t = \tau} \; d \, \tau$$i.e. if $$a_x (t) = \left \lvert \frac{ d\, x(t)}{d \, t } \right \rvert$$ then $$L_x = \int a_x (t) d t$$which basically means the total traveled distance along the $x$ axis along the curve. (This is the integral of the absolute value of the derivative I mentioned above.) Unfortunately, for a circular arc, it does not seem to lead to anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another comment, OP described their original problem to actually be finding the sum of monotonic spans in $x(t)$ (and separately for $y(t)$), where $\left( x(t) ,\, y(t) \right)$ describes a circular arc.

I don't see any simple algebraic formula for this, but there is a simple way to define it [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Let us assume we know the starting point of the circular arc, $A = ( x_A , y_A )$, the ending point of the circular arc, $B = ( x_B , y_B )$, and the center of the circular arc, $C = ( x_C , y_C )$. The radius $r$ is then $$r = \left\lVert \overline{AC} \right\rVert = \left\lVert \overline{BC} \right\rVert$$
ie. $$r = \sqrt{ ( x_C - x_A )^2 + ( y_C - y_A )^2 } = \sqrt{ ( x_C - x_B )^2 + ( y_C - y_B )^2 }$$

---

Before we delve further, it is important to note that there are multiple ways the circular arc could be defined. Consider the following image:

[image: Circular arcs]

All black lines are the same length, $r$, matching the radius of both circles.

There are four possibilities as to how the two points $A$ and $B$ can be connected via a circular arc of radius $r$.

First, the center $C$ can be either to the right of line $A B$ (at $C_R$), or to the left (at $C_L$ in the image).

Second, the arc could refer to the shorter or the longer segment of the circular arc.

For simplicity, I shall assume the arc is drawn counterclockwise from $A$ to $B$, with the center at $C_L$. In the image, it is the orangey curve passing near $C_R$.

Although the following scheme assumes this, you can still re-derive the logic for any other circular arc definition.

---

If we only know $A = ( x_A ,\, y_A )$, $B = ( x_B ,\, y_B )$, and the arc radius $r$, we can calculate the coordinates to the center of the arc, $C = C_L = ( x_C ,\, y_C )$, in the following way:

First, we calculate $\lVert\overline{AB}\rVert = d$:
$$d = \sqrt{ ( x_B - x_A )^2 + ( y_B - y_A )^2 }$$
Next, we form the unit vector from $A$ to $B$, $\hat{u} = ( x_u ,\, y_u )$:
$$\begin{cases} x_u = \frac{x_B - x_A}{d} \\
y_u = \frac{y_B - y_A}{d} \end{cases}$$
The other unit vector, $\hat{v} = ( x_v ,\, y_v )$, is the first one rotated 90° counterclockwise:
$$\begin{cases} x_v = -y_u \\ y_v = x_u \end{cases}$$

In the new $u, v$ coordinate system, $A = (0,0)$, $B = (d,0)$, and we are looking for the point $C = (u,v)$ where $u = d/2$ (due to symmetries), and $u^2 + v^2 = r^2$. Indeed,
$$\begin{cases} u = \frac{d}{2} \\
v = \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{d^2}{4}} \end{cases}$$
Since $C = C_L = A + u \hat{e}_u + v \hat{e}_v$, we find that
$$\begin{cases}
x_C = x_A + u x_u + v x_v \\
y_C = y_A + u y_u + v y_v \end{cases}$$
which simplify to
$$\begin{cases}
x_C = \frac{x_A + x_B}{2} + ( y_A - y_B ) \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{d^2} - \frac{1}{4}} \\
y_C = \frac{y_A + y_B}{2} + ( x_B - x_A ) \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{d^2} - \frac{1}{4}}  \end{cases}$$

If you want the $C = C_R$ center instead, use $-v$ instead; i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
x_C = \frac{x_A + x_B}{2} + ( y_B - y_A ) \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{d^2} - \frac{1}{4}} \\
y_C = \frac{y_A + y_B}{2} + ( x_A - x_B ) \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{d^2} - \frac{1}{4}}  \end{cases}$$

---

The crux of the piecewise definition is determining the [quadrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)) in which $A-C$ and $B-C$ are (i.e. starting and ending points with respect to center of the arc):
[image: Quadrants and rules for x and y]

If the arc is drawn counterclockwise, we can now look up the quadrants the curve passes in. Note that this works for both "short" (up to 180°) arcs and "long" (over 180°) arcs.

In the following array, each column specifies the quadrant $\overline{CA} = ( x_A - x_C ,\, y_A - y_C )$ is in, and each row specifies the quadrant $\overline{CB} = ( x_B - x_C ,\, y_B - y_C )$ is in. The numbers in each cell specify the quadrants, in counterclockwise order, the arc passes through:
$$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c}
\; & Q(\overline{CA})=1 & Q(\overline{CA})=2 & Q(\overline{CA})=3 & Q(\overline{CA})=4 \\
\hline
Q(\overline{CB})=1 & 1 & 2341 & 341 & 41 \\
\hline
Q(\overline{CB})=2 & 12 & 2 & 3412 & 412 \\
\hline
Q(\overline{CB})=3 & 123 & 23 & 3 & 4123 \\
\hline
Q(\overline{CB})=4 & 1234 & 234 & 34 & 4
\end{array}$$

If the arc passes through $12$, it passes the maximum $y$, $y_+ = y_C + r$.

If the arc passes through $23$, it passes the minimum $x$, $x_- = x_C - r$.

If the arc passes through $34$, it passes the minimum $y$, $y_- = y_C - r$.

If the arc passes through $41$, it passes the maximum $x$, $x_+ = x_C + r$.

Therefore, we can define a similar 4×4 table as above for the sum length of monotonic spans in $x$; picking the column based on the quadrant of $\overline{CA}$, and the row based on the quadrant of $\overline{CB}$:
$$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c}
\; & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
1 & f( x_A - x_B ) & 4 r + x_A - x_B & 2 x_+ - x_A - x_B & 2 x_+ - x_A - x_B \\
\hline
2 & x_A - x_B & f( x_A - x_B ) & 2 x_+ - x_A - x_B & 2 x_+ - x_A - x_B \\
\hline
3 & x_A + x_B - 2 x_- & x_A + x_B - 2 x_- & f( x_B - x_A ) & 4 r - x_A + x_B \\
\hline
4 & x_A + x_B - 2 x_- & x_A + x_B - 2 x_- & x_B - x_A & f( x_B - x_A )
\end{array}$$
where $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, & \text{ if } x \ge 0 \\
4 r + x, & \text{ if } x \lt 0 \end{cases}$$is needed to consider those arcs that are almost full circles (but start and end in the same quadrant).

The sum lengths of monotonic spans in $y$ along the arc are similarly
$$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c}
\; & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
1 & f( y_B - y_A ) & y_A + y_B - 2 y_- & y_A + y_B - 2 y_- & y_B - y_A \\
\hline
2 & 2 y_+ - y_A - y_B & f( y_A - y_B ) & 4 r + y_A - y_B & 2 y_+ - y_A - y_B \\
\hline
3 & 2 y_+ - y_A - y_B & y_A - y_B & f( y_A - y_B ) & 2 y_+ - y_A - y_B \\
\hline
4 & 4 r + y_B - y_A & y_A + y_B - 2 y_- & y_A + y_B - 2 y_- & f( y_B - y_A ) 
\end{array}$$

The lengths with $4 r$ are those that are almost a full circle. (For a full circle, the length in both axes is obviously $4 r$.)

I believe the above lengths are correct, but I have not tested/verified them (should be fairly easy to verify using randomly-generated values); so, there is a possibility of typos or thinkos. If you find any errors, please let me know in a comment, so I can verify and fix.

---

Here is an example C implementation, **sum_mono.c**. It is public domain, or equivalently, licensed under the [CC0 license](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) in jurisdictions that do not recognize "public domain". In other words, use as you wish on your own; but if it breaks something, you get to keep the pieces and not blame me.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Coordinate type.
 *
*/

typedef  double  coord;
#define COORDFMT "%.3f"

/*
 * 2D vector type.
*/
typedef struct {
    coord   x;
    coord   y;
} vec2d;

/* Return the quadrant:
 *      1 0     ^ y
 *      2 3     |-> x
 * Origin belongs to quadrant 0,
 * positive x axis to 0,
 * positive y axis to 1,
 * negative x axis to 2,
 * negative y axis to 3.
*/
static inline int quadrant(const vec2d p)
{
    if (p.y < 0 && p.x >= 0)
        return 3;
    else
    if (p.y <= 0 && p.x < 0)
        return 2;
    else
    if (p.y > 0 && p.x <= 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

/* Calculate the sum of monotonic spans in x and in y,
   with a circular arc from p0 to p1,
   counterclockwise in a right-handed coordinate system,
   with the center at origin (0,0) and radius r,
   p0.x*p0.x + p0.y*p0.y = r*r = p1.x*p1.x + p1.y*p1.y.

   If you have center at c, starting point at a, and
   ending point at b, with |ca| = |cb| = r, then use
       monosum(a - c, b - c, r)
   but remember, this picks the counterclockwise arc
   (which can be the shorter or the longer part of the
    full circle).
*/
static vec2d sum_mono(const vec2d p0, const vec2d p1, const double r)
{
    vec2d  result;

    switch (quadrant(p1) + 4*quadrant(p0)) {

    case 0:  /* 0    */
        if (p1.x <= p0.x && p1.y >= p0.y) {
            result.x = p0.x - p1.x;
            result.y = p1.y - p0.y;
        } else {
            result.x = r + r + r + r + p0.x - p1.x;
            result.y = r + r + r + r + p1.y - p0.y;
        }
        return result;

    case 1:  /* 01   */
        result.x = p0.x - p1.x;
        result.y = r + r - p0.y - p1.y;
        return result;

    case 2:  /* 012  */
        result.x = r + r + p0.x + p1.x;
        result.y = r + r - p0.y - p1.y; 
        return result;

    case 3:  /* 0123 */
        result.x = r + r + p0.x + p1.x;
        result.y = r + r + r + r + p1.y - p0.y;
        return result;

    case 4:  /* 1230 */
        result.x = r + r + r + r + p0.x - p1.x;
        result.y = r + r + p0.y + p1.y;
        return result;

    case 5:  /* 1    */
        if (p1.x <= p0.x && p1.y <= p0.y) {
            result.x = p0.x - p1.x;
            result.y = p0.y - p1.y;
        } else {
            result.x = r + r + r + r + p0.x - p1.x;
            result.y = r + r + r + r + p0.y - p1.y;
        }
        return result;

    case 6:  /* 12   */
        result.x = r + r + p0.x + p1.x;
        result.y = p0.y - p1.y;
        return result;

    case 7:  /* 123  */
        result.x = r + r + p0.x + p1.x;
        result.y = r + r + p0.y + p1.y;
        return result;

    case 8:  /* 230  */
        result.x = r + r - p0.x - p1.x;
        result.y = r + r + p0.y + p1.y;
        return result;

    case 9:  /* 2301 */
        result.x = r + r - p0.x - p1.x;
        result.y = r + r + r + r + p0.y - p1.y;
        return result;

    case 10: /* 2    */
        if (p0.x <= p1.x && p0.y >= p1.y) {
            result.x = p1.x - p0.x;
            result.y = p0.y - p1.y;
        } else {
            result.x = r + r + r + r + p1.x - p0.x;
            result.y = r + r + r + r + p0.y - p1.y;
        }
        return result;

    case 11: /* 23   */
        result.x = p1.x - p0.x;
        result.y = r + r + p0.y + p1.y;
        return result;

    case 12: /* 30   */
        result.x = r + r - p0.x - p1.x;
        result.y = p1.y - p0.y;
        return result;

    case 13: /* 301  */
        result.x = r + r - p0.x - p1.x;
        result.y = r + r - p0.y - p1.y;
        return result;

    case 14: /* 3012 */
        result.x = r + r + r + r + p1.x - p0.x;
        result.y = r + r - p0.y - p1.y;
        return result;

    default: /* 3    */
        if (p0.x <= p1.x && p0.y <= p1.y) {
            result.x = p1.x - p0.x;
            result.y = p1.y - p0.y;
        } else {
            result.x = r + r + r + r + p1.x - p0.x;
            result.y = r + r + r + r + p1.y - p0.y;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

/* Helper function: Returns a point with radius 5:
 *         3
 *     4       2
 *    5         1
 *   6           0
 *    7        11
 *     8      10
 *         9
 * This is useful as a test set, because the points
 * have integer coordinates.
*/
static vec2d radius5(const int a)
{
    vec2d result;

    switch (a) {
    case  0: result.x = +5; result.y =  0; return result;
    case  1: result.x = +4; result.y = +3; return result;
    case  2: result.x = +3; result.y = +4; return result;
    case  3: result.x =  0; result.y = +5; return result;
    case  4: result.x = -3; result.y = +4; return result;
    case  5: result.x = -4; result.y = +3; return result;
    case  6: result.x = -5; result.y =  0; return result;
    case  7: result.x = -4; result.y = -3; return result;
    case  8: result.x = -3; result.y = -4; return result;
    case  9: result.x =  0; result.y = -5; return result;
    case 10: result.x = +3; result.y = -4; return result;
    case 11: result.x = +4; result.y = -3; return result;
    default: result.x =  0; result.y =  0; return result;
    }
}

/*
 * Given two indexes referring to radius5 vectors,
 * calculates the sum of monotonic parts along the x and
 * y axes, by summing the differences between consecutive
 * vectors in the radius5 set.
*/
static vec2d radius5_sum_mono(const int a0, const int a1)
{
    vec2d result = { 0, 0 };
    vec2d curr, prev;
    int  a = a0;

    if (a0 == a1)
        return result;

    curr = radius5(a);

    do {
        prev = curr;
        a = (a + 1) % 12;
        curr = radius5(a);

        if (curr.x >= prev.x)
            result.x += curr.x - prev.x;
        else
            result.x += prev.x - curr.x;

        if (curr.y >= prev.y)
            result.y += curr.y - prev.y;
        else
            result.y += prev.y - curr.y;

    } while (a != a1);

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a0, a1;
    int failures = 0;

    for (a0 = 0; a0 < 12; a0++) {
        const vec2d  v0 = radius5(a0);
        for (a1 = 0; a1 < 12; a1++) {
            const vec2d  correct = radius5_sum_mono(a0, a1);
            const vec2d  v1 = radius5(a1);
            const vec2d  calculated = sum_mono(v0, v1, 5);

            if (calculated.x != correct.x) {
                failures++;
                printf("Radius5(%d,%d) (Q%d%d): Lx = " COORDFMT ", not " COORDFMT "!\n",
                       a0, a1, quadrant(v0), quadrant(v1), correct.x, calculated.x);
            }

            if (calculated.y != correct.y) {
                failures++;
                printf("Radius5(%d,%d) (Q%d%d): Ly = " COORDFMT ", not " COORDFMT "!\n",
                       a0, a1, quadrant(v0), quadrant(v1), correct.y, calculated.y);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!failures)
        printf("Radius5 checks all passed.\n");
    else
        printf("Radius5 checks: %d out of 288 failed.\n", failures);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The function `sum_mono(ca, cb, r)` computes the sum of monotonic spans in both x and y, given a counterclockwise circular arc of radius `r`, with starting point relative to center of arc at `ca`, and ending point relative to center of arc at `cb`. (Essentially, `ca`·`ca` = `r*r` = `cb`·`cb`.)

The main program tests 12×12 arcs of radius 5, the ones that have integer coordinates, so that you can change `coord` to `float` or `int`, but still have the verification work correctly. It verifies `sum_mono()` by comparing to a function that sums the deltas of successive integer-coordinated vectors within the arc; I consider it a good initial check.

Comment: loved it,that's exactly what i had in mind but mathematically proven ^^, i use a version of this as a c code for project i'm working on, that's why i was asking for a straight formula to reduce the processing time and memory consumption cause it runs on a MCU, thanks alot man, though i would love to check your 'c' example of it; since its off-topic we can chat it out or email me "o.emad@outlook.com".

Comment: @O.Emad: I think the topic is weird enough to warrant including the example C code here. You can change to `typedef int coord;` and `#define COORDFMT "%d"` to use integer coordinates instead. The `sum_mono()` function uses only comparisons, additions, and substractions wrt. coordinates, so it should be quite fast. I just wish we could reword your question to open the topic to others here, too. (I do not know the correct mathematical terms, myself; *"sum of monotonic spans"* is just my best quess.)

Comment: Question reworded, and thanks again that have been a great help

Answer (score 0):

OP clarified in the comment that the actual question is

> What is the height $Y$ of a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), when we know the radius $r$ and the chord length $d$?

[image: Circular arc chord and segment]

OP is looking for $Y = r - h$.

Elementary trigonometry says that
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{h}{r} \qquad \iff \qquad h = r \cos(\theta)$$
and that
$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}{r} = \frac{d}{2 r}$$

The problem is to find $r - h$:
$$r - h = r - r \cos(\theta) = r \left ( 1 - \cos(\theta) \right )$$

In OP's situation, where $d$ is the distance between two given points, and $r$ is the known radius of the circular arc, we can assume that $0 \le d \le 2 r$. (That is, if the two points are further than $2 r$ away from each other, no circular arc of radius $r$ can reach both points.)

In this case, $$0 \le \frac{d}{2 r} \le 1$$
and therefore $0° \le \theta \le 90°$. This means that
$$\cos(\theta) = \sqrt{1 - \left ( \sin(\theta) \right )^2 } = \sqrt{1 - \left ( \frac{d}{2 r} \right )^2 }$$

With this, we find the solution:
$$r - h = r \left ( 1 - \sqrt{ 1 - \left ( \frac{d}{2 r} \right )^2 } \right )$$

---

If the circular arc is defined by two points, $A = ( x_A , y_A )$ and $B = ( x_B , y_B )$, and the radius $r$, then
$$Y = r - h = r \left ( 1 - \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{ ( x_B - x_A )^2 + ( y_B - y_A )^2 }{ 4 r^2 } } \right )$$

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but this formula seems to work only in the 2 points have the same y value to keep line d horizontal and perpendicular to y axis, if the two points doesn't have the same y value you can no longer define sin(θ)  as d/2r cause its no longer a right angle triangle.

Comment: @O.Emad: What? That is so incorrect claim that I'm stunned. Did you even read the answer? I defined $Y = r - h$, to match your linked image! It has nothing to do with $y$ coordinates or the $y$ axis. $Y$ is simply the name of the variable that describes the height of the circular segment. It is equal to $r - h$, where $r$ is the arc radius, and $h$ is the minimum distance from the center of the arc to the chord. The two right angle triangles in the image are the halves of the arc. There are **always** two. They both have angle $\theta$, because the entire arc covers $2 \theta$.

Comment: "The two right angle triangles in the image are the halves of the arc. There are always two. They both have angle θ, because the entire arc covers 2θ", that's true as long as the chord is perpendicular to y axis,, "arc is symmetric about y axis", i know the way i introduced the problem is vague and i'm sorry for that. your answer is good start for me, but its not what i'm looking for,, thanks for your time.

Comment: @O.Emad: Consider the case where you have a circular arc of radius 1 from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$. In this case, $r - h$ is the same as above, $1 - \sqrt{2}/2$. $x$ coordinates range from $0$ to $1$, and $y$ coordinates from $1$ to 0. In fact, in this particular case, the curve is $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$. Can you tell me what the quantity you are looking for would be in this case? (Maximum deviation along some axis or vector from the chord line to the curve?) If you can, we might actually get to the bottom of what you are looking for.

Comment: okay, hope i can clarify, what i'm looking for is the total distance moved over each axis to achieve the parametric form of the circle,using you proposed case the two points are in the first quadrant so the object moved 1 unit on x axis and 1 unit on y axis, if the two points are on two different quadrants like A(1,0) B(-1,0) the object moved 2 units on x axis and 2 units on y axis, that i could calculate logically because for an object that has to move from A to B in a circular manner it has to pass by the head point C (0,1) for a counter clockwise motion...continued

Comment: so the distance over y would be ||(ya-yc)||+||(yc-yb)|| = ||(0-1)||+||(1-0)|| = 2. that's what i wanna calculate but without using intermediate point C , just using points A,B and raduis, same thing happens but with x axis when one point is in the 2nd quadrant and the other one on the 3rd quadrant. hope the problem is obvious now ^^

Comment: @O.Emad: So, if we define the curve as $\left( x(t) ,\, y(t) \right )$ for say $0 \le t \le 1$, $L_x$ is the sum length of monotonic parts in $x(t)$, and $L_y$ the sum length of monotonic parts in $y(t)$? Monotonic means either ascending or descending, but not both in the same part. So, if $x$ reaches a maximum between the two points, $L_x$ is *(from initial $x$ to maximum $x$)* + *(from maximum $x$ to final $x$)*? Same for minimum, and similarly for the $y$ coordinate?

Comment: yes, that sounds like it.

Comment: @O.Emad: Okay, I added [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2324488/318422) on how I would solve it. I do not believe there is a simple analytical form; I believe that a piecewise solution is the only choice. If you can comment (in the other answer) as to exactly **why** you need this, or how you intend to use it, I might be interested enough to show some example C/Awk/Python code (also verifying the formulas in the lookup tables).